# How two draw a two-head vector and curly brace in picture environment?

Tags: miktex, arrows, braces

I want to insert a two-head vector, and a curly brace of length of my choice, as shown in figure below

[image]

[image]

in the `picture` environment and want to `put` it on the specified location.
Unable to find any reasonable hint for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(100,100)

\put(20,20){\vector(-1,0){0}}
\put(20,20){\vector(1,0){50}}
\put(30,60){\makebox(200,5){\upbracefill}}

\end{picture}
\end{document}
```